# Could the change from an edit be displayed in a side-by-side display

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, diff

Being a foreign language speaker (or writer and reader to be more exact) I would prefer to see the changes in a side by side diff tool.

The current format with the two above each other doesn't make it easy to recognize the improvements.

Comment: You should have a look at [Side--by-side editor](http://stackapps.com/questions/2245/stack-exchange-side-by-side-edit-and-preview) userscript

Answer (score 12):

The revision diff list now offers a side-by-side diff in addition to the inline diff. Because of the page width issues Jeff mentions, they're narrower than the final output (just like the side-by-side diff for suggested edits), but they're there.

Comment: WONDERFUL!!!!!!!

Comment: Thrilling and incredibly useful feature!

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented this feature request as a user script.

See **[Stack Exchange Side-By-Side  Edit and Preview](https://stackapps.com/q/2245/5930)** on StackApps.