# Have a mod tag that removes vote locks from child meta posts

Tags: feature-request, tags, voting, moderator-tools, per-site-meta

Note: I've seen similar posts to this, but I haven't seen anything such as a feature request in my searches. However, this in a sense expands on Camil Staps post, which is found here: [Don't lock votes on Meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171694/dont-lock-votes-on-meta-sites).

---

On many meta posts on child sites, there are various sorts of posts where the community registers their thoughts through voting. Such posts include moderator nominations, and specific feature requests that concern critical site development (these posts are normally started by moderators). On these posts, you have a vote. You place it, and then it's there for good. Unless someone edits it or anything. Regardless, any solutions are extremely hacky, and require community users with higher reputation, which makes things like these significantly harder for betas, particularly those in a private beta.

#### My Feature Request

I would like to propose the addition of a tag. Here's some points:

- The tag would be a moderator only tag: This would ensure that it is only used in appropriate situations, and to prevent any sorts of abuse of the tag when used on posts that should have these features.
- Obviously, it would only apply to meta posts.
- The tag could be similar to the [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. The addition of the tag onto a post would affect the question and answers themselves, immediately adding "free voting" onto all the posts.
- Allowing free voting on specific posts will allow people to accurately register their opinions. With posts such as moderator nominations in betas, people also look at activity overtime, and then retract, or add their support to the nominee accordingly. This would allow users to be flexible, and *encourage voting*, as I have a hunch that there are users who don't vote at all out of fear of uncertainty, or who don't vote at all because they lock.
- Posts which are controversial, or bring forth large amounts of discussion will highly benefits from "free voting," as opinions will changes after perspectives are revealed and such.
- Having such a tag would control the "free" voting. Unlocking votes, as shown in Camil Staps post linked above, on the entire meta site would bring it also to cases where it is inappropriate, particularly in [support](/questions/tagged/support) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) questions.

I think that this is also a good compromise for voting on meta sites. Instead of going for a full-fledged no locks on votes thing, and instead of keeping the status-quo in which all votes are locked, this is a balance so that the posts that need these features can utilize them.

I'm not sure about what we would name such as a tag. I would think making it similar to the way the [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag is worded, thus making it something like [community-thoughts] or something like that. I'm looking forward to hearing thoughts on this. :)

Comment: Why limit this to child metas? MSE is a meta site also ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I disagree with this feature request. After voting on a post, you have the opportunity to retract it; once that time is up, I think it makes sense to lock the votes. This ensures that answers that are wildly upvoted/downvoted won't suddenly switch (unless, of course, they've been edited). This feature request would thus make it difficult to get a feel for community consensus on issues.

Comment: Posts will only suddenly switch if people suddenly change their minds. In such a case, it will be difficult to get a feel for the consensus because there clearly is no such consensus. Locking votes in these cases is an attempt to lock people's opinions in at a given time. If the real point is to ascertain the community's views, the means has to reflect changes in those views. If the community is extremely fickle, the votes will reflect that. It will be hard then to say what the community thinks but only because the community itself is not clear what it thinks.

Comment: @cfr Fair point. I think you've gotten me to change my mind. Wish I could undo my downvote on the question, though....

Comment: Maybe it will get edited... ;).

Comment: Lol, I guess going through this, you see the rationale for the request. Controversial issues and everything could probably benefit from all this.

Comment: Community consensus changes over time. So also should community votes.

Answer (score -1):

I agree... with Shokhet. I disagree with this feature request.

I don't think it is useful to be able to redo my vote on a post, when the post hasn't changed, and if I would, I don't expect a moderator to decide which posts get a second change and which not. This feature request is based on the assumption that:

1. The post does not get edited in considerable time (that would make this request useless);
2. A lot of people vote 'the wrong way'. In my opinion, this makes clear the post should be edited to make clear why a user should vote either way;
3. A moderator can assess that a lot of users are 'waiting' to reverse their vote. Even if he/she could, an edit would suffice to have a chance to reverse the vote.

I don't see why you want to have a post that has unlimited vote changes.

> This would allow users to be flexible, and encourage voting, as I have a hunch that there are users who don't vote at all out of fear of uncertainty, or who don't vote at all because they lock.

This will allow users to **wildly** vote without reading and change their mind later on. Something we don't want.

Comment: And what about discussion in comments, chat. What about site changing issues, where the community is split? Where off-post developments occur. I shouldn't have to go through hacky situations just to reverse a vote.

Comment: Posts can add arguments over time. That would make it valid to revert your vote. You vote on a post as is at that time. If you want add an argument separately from the question, post an answer.

Comment: Really? Not *all* posts arguments over time... What about things such as moderator nominations?

Comment: If you can't assess how a user has contributed to the site over the time of a year, why change your mind after one or two comments?

Comment: It's not just comments though. It's community activity on the main site. There are all of these different factors that you have to take into account.

Comment: And what exactly does a meta post about nominations have to do with the end result of an election? Why care so much?

Comment: ***Nominations***. On beta site for pro tem appointments if that helps in being more clear. It's just an example: There can be multiple issues as well. This is not a community tag where it will apply to everything: It's a moderator tag so it will be used on appropriate posts.

Comment: I still don't get how a moderator has a role here.

Comment: Are you expecting this to be a community tag then?

Comment: *If* it has to be introduced, do it on specific tags, like [tag:moderator-nominations] for example. This will prevent the feel that moderators police the votes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/919/discussion-between-zizouz212-and-patrick-hofman).