# Should we be able to change our votes more freely on a meta site?

Tags: feature-request, voting, per-site-meta

On a meta site, votes are intended to imply agreement with the question/answer. In contrast, votes are intended to imply *quality*, on the general site. Overall, when we cast a vote, we have a *brief window* to reverse or withdraw that vote. Once this window has passed, our votes are locked in, unless an edit is applied to that post.

---

This makes sense, in general. When we judge a post for it's quality, there is little reason<sup>1</sup> to want to legitimately withdraw or reverse this vote, unless the post *has* had changes made to it. Without change, the quality of the answer is also unchanged.

In contrast, *opinion does change*. When I vote on meta, I am voicing agreement or disagreement with the post. I think it is a lot more plausible that this stance *could* change, *without* an edit to the original post.

---

[Here is a good example of one such case](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2309/should-we-delete-or-clarify-the-scale-tag). I asked a question regarding a particular tag that needed more clarity in it's usage. A user suggested an alternate to my own proposed solution, and I agreed that it was a better proposal. I deleted my original answer, and up-voted the new answer. Some time after, a user with more experience posted an alternate answer. With the clarity of the explanation provided in the new answer, I no longer agreed with the previous answer. However, I am still technically *voicing* agreement in the answer, as I can not undo my vote.

*In some cases*, this may appear as a "non-event". One vote should not make a difference. However, in cases where meta-usage is not as common, I feel it *does* make a significant impact on the overall view of the topic or suggestion.

*I have previously been directed to simply perform an edit*; I feel this is not a suitable option. Especially in certain cases where such edits would be semantic and questionable.

---

Can we have a bit more freedom in retracting and/or reversing votes in Meta?

It occurred to me that there might be further issues if this was implemented on the main meta site (i.e. this one), as reputation is awarded. I am asking *specifically* for *site-specific* meta, though I don't see why we couldn't *discuss* implementing this, here.

<sub><sup>1</sup> [Tim losing his keys, for example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught)</sub>

Comment: Further reading: [extremely similar request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171694/295684).