# View summary of changes while editing

Tags: feature-request, edits, user-interface

In the revision history of edited posts, there is a helpful display that highlights the changes between the edited and the original. Often, while editing, I find myself looking back at the original question in another tab to make sure I've covered everything and haven't accidentally deleted anything (moving the mouse a few pixels too far while selecting lines to change, that sort of thing). It would be much more convenient, and I would be less prone to "oops, I missed a spot, too bad I can't edit my edit without submitting another edit" if I could see the same display from the revision history showing both the original question and what changes have been made while editing.

Comment: and/or [Let me preview an edit so that it appears with the same style as revisions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126075/135887), one of these should dupe the other...