# Show original question during editing a question

Tags: feature-request, edits

I found some questions that are not very well-worded, and I want to clarify them. So, I went, and edited one of the questions.

As I have poor short-term memory, after editing, I wondered what I have edited.

I cannot find any easy way to see the original version, or a diff.

Of course, I could just click "Back" button to see the question, but I risk losing my edit (in case I just happen to navigate away and lost the "Next" button.) It is inconvenient too. I wish I could make a comparison to ensure the original meaning remains unchanged.

Did I miss anything? I looked around and found [Add an option for side-by-side diff before posting an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78652/add-an-option-for-side-by-side-diff-before-posting-an-edit), but I cannot just submit the (suggested) edit, which defeats the point that I want to review my edit before submitting/suggesting.

It shows the original question when editing answers, but not editing questions themselves.

---

In short, may the edit question page shows the original, or a link to it? (I don't find it, I do not have edit privilege if that matters.)

This is what I have, can anyone point out how to access the original question?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Open the original question in a new tab?  The title is a link at the top of the page so a CTRL/CMD click should do the trick quite easily.

Comment: But there isn't any link to original question when you are already editing

Comment: There is, the title doesn't change when editing begins.  Try it out :-)

Comment: No, I don't find it, maybe because I do not have enough rep?? I do not have edit privilege...

Comment: @luiges90: Suggesting an edit or editing directly doesn't factor into it. Try it out without submitting an edit, the edit page title is a link back to the question. Even *anonymous* visitors can suggest an edit, so you have enough rep for that.

Comment: Seriously, I cannot find the link. I have attached my screenshot, can anyone point out where is it? The title is a text field. Sorry if I was negligence...

Comment: @Rory: luiges is right. There is no link if you don't have the inline editor.

Comment: @Mat Ahh didn't clock that it was inline only - still it is still possible to do a CTRL click on the back button to open it on the new tab.  Sorry for the confusion luiges90!

Comment: Oh I didn't know I can Ctrl-click the Back button, though it would be good to include a link somewhere as not everyone knows the Ctrl-click trick. :)

Comment: @Rory Wow. I had no idea you could ctrl-click the back button. This will revolutionize my web browsing experience.